# Cant access to wp admin appear a dot

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed WP and now when I try to access to the panel (`www.my_domain.com/wp-admin/`) I write the user and the password, but then only a dot appears.

I installed it by softaculous.

This is all I know, if you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Step to install wordpress. I will use local host to demonstrate the process of installations.

1. Download Wordpress From [Here](https://wordpress.org/download/)  Go to your FTP and upload under
   public_html or www folder. Since i am using local machine. I will just put under htdocs. 
   [image: Files under htdocs]

   2. After that go to your php admin and create a new Database. Just remember your db name and its password. We will need it for later.
   3. Now Go to your www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin. Mine is under htdocs/wordpress .So i have to call http://localhost/wordpress/ or you can call also http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin. You will see as below
      [image: intro]
      4.Click next and you will see the following page.Fill in DB name, username pw and host.  My Db name is calle wordpress_test. and username is "root" without pasword. DB host is in local. 
      [image]
      5.After that add in information as you want. Do Username and password.[image]
   4. If you see the below message. You are good to go ! If not check your information provided to wordpress again. 
      [image]
   5. Now You Can Log in from http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin with provided username and password [image]
   6. And you will see wordpress dashboard. Enjoy Wordpress!!!! 
      [image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of the plugins folder and try deleting all the plugins from the folder and then check.

Also check for spaces in top and bottom of functions.php page (no spaces should be present)